# why python vim module gives different result on ms windows and ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, python

On windows xp and vim 7.3.1105 (Yongwei's build):

```
:tabnew
:py import vim
:py print(type(vim.current.buffer.name))
<type 'str'> -- THIS
```

on ubuntu  and vim 7.3.1020 (my own build):

```
:tabnew
:py import vim
:py print(type(vim.current.buffer.name))
<type 'NoneType'> -- AND THIS
```

why this difference?

Comment: What string does the Windows build give you?  I think this is too localized to be honest, it really depends on the implementation of the `vim` module... Do you get this behaviour on any other operating systems?

Comment: after ':tabnew', the buffer.name is '' (windows) or None (ubuntu).

Comment: That's what I suspected... I'd expect that Ubuntu would return a string if the buffer name was non-null, but it's just a blank string even on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many recent changes to the Python interface (mainly done by ZyX) in order to improve the Python interface. Python imports have been reworked, too.

Probably the discrepancy is due to the different Vim patch levels. Try again with identical Vim versions. If you have problems with the changed behavior, or detailed questions, please ask them on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). As long as development towards Vim 7.4 is ongoing, the group is still very open to feedback and bug reports.